# Last Seen update frequency design problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `DateTime LastSeen` property that stores in the database when the user was last seen.

I have 1 way in mind when to update the database is to do it when validating the user during logging in.

Another way is if I'm going to update the database every 20 minutes, where do I put this logic in asp.net mvc? Do I need to set a `lastupdate` in the cookie and check that? Where would I check this cookie other than in the *global.ascx.* file?

How do other systems do it?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would take a page out of google analytics' book and run this client side. To get there:

a) Setup a Handler/Action/something that takes http requests to handle recording user "seen" activities
b) Setup an ajax call to (a) to record activities at a reasonable interval from the client.

This will let you get to a much better answer to the question "what if bob just opened the site, saw he didn't have any messages and went on browsing [whatever]"

Answer (score 0):

I think as you suggest, update that value when the user logs on would be simplest.

If you model also has CreatedOn, CreatedBy, ModifiedOn, ModifiedBy properties you can also query these values with a join onto the user table to see if they have been active elsewhere in the app but this may not be great in performance as you'll need a join on every table in your database.